# Не отображаются карты яндекс

Tags: javascript

У меня карты не отображаются. Я координаты подставляю, через data. Если напрямую прописываю, то работает.  В чем может быть причина? Буду рад любой помощи!
координаты приходят:

```
 console.log(seasonList[i].dataset.coord);
```

ymaps.ready(init);

```
function init() {
let seasonList = document.getElementsByClassName("contacts-title")
for(let i = 0; i < seasonList.length; i++) {
  console.log(seasonList[i].dataset.coord);
var myMap = new ymaps.Map (`map${seasonList[i].dataset.id}`, {
        center: [seasonList[i].dataset.coord],
        zoom: 10
    });
    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([seasonList[i].dataset.coord], { 
        iconContent: 'Москва', 
        balloonContent: 'Столица России' 
    }, {
        preset: 'twirl#blueStretchyIcon'
    });

}
}
```